# Preprocessing text so that two words without a separating space (or hyphen separated) are detected

Tags: preprocessing, text

Let's say I have a text corpus with inconsistently written bi-grams. An example would be "bi gram", "bi-gram", "bigram". Is there any standard text preprocessing method to normalize all these as the same thing? i.e. replace all such occurrences by "bigram". I should also mention that I have no prior knowledge of what exact bi-grams  are present in the corpus.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote? I'm not sure what's wrong with the question

Comment: It seems you are asking two questions at the same time. Try to post your second question separately.

Comment: @lcrmorin: Thanks! I have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Two possible strategies:

1. Hard coded rules
2. Statistical learning

Hard coded rules means creating a mapping from original text to the normalized representations.  The text will have to be manually inspected to find commonly occurring patterns. Hard coded rules are often done with regular expressions.

A statistical learning approach looks for patterns in the data. [Bigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram#Details) can be defined as the conditional probability of a token given the preceding token. When that probability is above a threshold the two tokens are merged.